# LogiXML Studio - Logi Report force page break

Tags: intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

I'm not sure how wide the Logi Report user audience is that watches the site, but here's my dilemma. I new to find a way to force a page break after a group summary row. It is of course easy to do if printing (or exporting to pdf or the like) due to the printer page break option in the group summary row. But how can I force a page break after the group summary row when viewing the report normally? Any help would be great! Let me know if you need anything from me!
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to construct your grouping such that you're using Sub Reports or Sub Data Tables instead of building a single table structure.  That way, you can assign the InteractivePaging element to use 1 row per page;  the effect will be to force a page break (new interactive page) for each group of data.

here's a simple example using static data, feel free to copy/paste this directly into a new definition inside Logi studio :

```
<DataTable ID="dt" Width="500" WidthScale="px">
  <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="dlStatic1">
    <StaticDataRow Category="Beverages" />
    <StaticDataRow Category="Condiments" />
    <StaticDataRow Category="Meat and Poultry" />
  </DataLayer>
  <DataTableColumn ID="colCategory" Header="Category">
    <Label ID="lblCategory" Caption="@Data.Category~" />
    <DataColumnSort DataColumn="Category" />
  </DataTableColumn>
  <MoreInfoRow>
    <SubDataTable ID="dtSub" Width="80" WidthScale="%">
      <SubDataLayer ID="subDL">
        <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="dlStatic2">
          <StaticDataRow Category="Beverages" Product="Coffee" Price="7.99" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Beverages" Product="Tea" Price="5.99" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Beverages" Product="Milk" Price="3.49" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Condiments" Product="Mustard" Price="1.99" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Condiments" Product="Mayo" Price="3.99" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Condiments" Product="Oil" Price="6.99" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Meat and Poultry" Product="Steak" Price="15.75" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Meat and Poultry" Product="Chicken" Price="8.55" />
          <StaticDataRow Category="Meat and Poultry" Product="Pork" Price="7.45" />
        </DataLayer>
        <SubDataLayerRelationColumn ChildColumn="Category" ParentColumn="Category" ID="relCategory" />
      </SubDataLayer>
      <DataTableColumn ID="colProduct" Header="Products">
        <Label Caption="@Data.Product~" ID="lblProduct" />
      </DataTableColumn>
      <DataTableColumn ID="colPrice" Header="Price">
        <Label Caption="@Data.Price~" ID="lblPrice" />
      </DataTableColumn>
    </SubDataTable>
  </MoreInfoRow>
  <InteractivePaging CaptionType="Image" PageRowCount="1" Location="Top" ShowPageNumber="True" />
</DataTable>
```

You might find additional examples of a similar structure on Logi DevNet as well :  http://devnet.logixml.com/

The "hierarchical" table Sample on the samples page (under DataTables section) also illustrates similar report layouts.

Comment: Right, we originally wrote the report like that. However the issues becomes breaking the subreport. There is no way to break the page based on number of rows in a sub report, at least according to my knowledge. Any input?

Comment: It is possible to have multiple sub-reports or sub-dataTables under each parent, eg.  there's no limit to the number of hierarchical levels you can create, provided your data supports these hierarchical relationships.

If you go with the SubReport model, each child sub-report can utilize it's own pagination control as well.